# Multibit balance does not match blockchain balance. Weird extra bitcoins appear. Now the are gone plus some?

Tags: multibit, lost-transactions, lost-bitcoins

So, really weird. Went to send some bitcoins to another of my wallets and all went as expected. I sent 1.013 BTC from a balance of about 3.01254367 BTC. My girlfriend then went to make a withdrawal. She said the balance was just over 4 BTC before the withdrawal which it couldn't have been because of my last transaction. It should have been just over 2 BTC. She said she sent 4 BTC leaving about 0.5 BTC in wallet. The transaction stuck, that was when I got involved to sort it all out!

I reset the blockchain and transactions on multibit and now the balance is 0.97 which doesn't seem to match up with anything? The transaction has shown up on the blockchain at all but I'm down by about 1 BTC.

Answer (score 2):

What version are you on ? If you have earlier than 0.5.9 I recommend upgrading. The latest code also picks up pending transactions when you do a reset.

Also, you might want to do a reset blockchain from before when you created the wallet to make sure you have all the transactions on the blockchain.

Comment: stil diddnt solve my problem, i got the same thing.
my money disapeard from balance in multibit but on blockchain its the same....

Answer (score 1):

if you're sending from a paper wallet loaded onto multibit you have to send all the bitcoins in one transaction or the remainder will be sent "back" as "change" to an address you don't control (controlled by Multibit).
Use Armory.